# Blender 2.8 edit mode. I can see through parts of my model

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I finally decided to start using blender 2.8, I've gotten a lot of things looking right again but I've ran into an issue in edit mode, I can see through parts of my model at times, and if i zoom out I can see all of the facedots. Is this a bug, or a new feature? [image: The facedots and some of the edges can be seen through the mesh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I noticed that Viewport clipping now affects the visibility of the face dots in 2.8+ and I can see through my mesh when at the lowest Clip Start setting of 0.001. I changed mine to 0.002 and it seems to fix the problem but I like to zoom in close & I hate viewport clipping, so it is still a minor annoyance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little more information and visual examples would be helpful to verify exactly what is going on. It could be a couple things. Could be a feature or a bug(given the fact that 2.8 is still in beta). I want to lean more towards a possible bug.

There is a feature that can do what it sounds like you might be describing, in terms of "seeing through the mesh". However it appears disabled in your Header at the bottom of the viewport.

The button in the Header [image: transparency button] allows you to make the whole scene transparent when enabled. Therefore see through the mesh. But only seeing the face dots and not the wireframe is why I think its a bug.

Image 1 transparency of the scene is disabled.
[image: image 1]

Image 2 transparency is enabled.
[image]

According to your image you are using v2.80.39. I am using v2.80.45 and cannot recreate your issue exactly.

I would recommend updating to a newer version of the beta(nightly builds), and see if the issue remains.

I could be wrong, but unless someone else can state otherwise and educate us both, I'm guessing its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the problem is you have created an object in an older version of Blender, 2.79 say, and you have opened that object in a newer version, like 2.80.

The data structures have changed, and the pointers don't point where they should.

I think you'll have to either rebuild your model in the newer version of Blender, or go back to using the older version. I opted to rebuild mine in the newer version.

You can verify this: construct a simple object in the newer version of Blender, and see whether that new object behaves as expected.